# Jackson polymorphic deserialization with type property that is nested in object

Tags: java, jackson, polymorphism, deserialization

I'm trying to find out a way to use the polymorphic deserialization feature of jackson  in a way that it will deserialize my object based on a property that is nested in header/control object:

JSON 1 - CATEGORY1:

```
{
 "id":"someId",
 "header":{
           "category":"CATEGORY1",
           "somOtherProperty":"someValue"
          }
 "nextField":"nextValue",
 ...
}
```

JSON 2 - CATEGORY2

```
{
 "id":"someId",
 "header":{
           "category":"CATEGORY2",
           "somOtherProperty":"someValue"
          }
 "nextField":"nextValue",
 ...
}
```

Parent Class (annotations something like this)

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "category")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(value = Category1Class.class, name = "CATEGORY1"), 
        @Type(value = Category2Class.class, name = "CATEGORY2") })
public class ParentClass{
    private Header header;
    private String nextField;
    ...
}

public class Header{
    private String category;
    private String somOtherProperty;
    ...
}
```

Child classes

```
@JsonTypeName("CATEGORY1")
public class Category1Class extends ParentClass{
    ...
}

@JsonTypeName("CATEGORY2")
public class Category2Class extends ParentClass{
    ...
}
```

Is there an out of the box functionality in jackson that would enable me to do this kind of deserialization or am I missing something?

Comment: see https://www.thomaskeller.biz/blog/2013/09/10/custom-polymorphic-type-handling-with-jackson/

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the Jackson Api `AsPropertyTypeDeserializer` is the class responsible for sub type identification using property. If you look at that class there is a method called `deserializeTypedFromObject` which will identify the subclass using `JsonTypeIdResolver`. We can extend this class and override methods `deserializeTypedFromObject` and `forProperty`.

```
package com.dilipkumarg.tutorials.dynamicsubtype;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.TypeDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.TypeIdResolver;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TreeTraversingParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.SimpleType;

public class CustomTypeDeserializer extends AsPropertyTypeDeserializer {
public CustomTypeDeserializer(
        final JavaType bt, final TypeIdResolver idRes,
        final String typePropertyName, final boolean typeIdVisible, final Class<?> defaultImpl) {
    super(bt, idRes, typePropertyName, typeIdVisible, defaultImpl);
}

public CustomTypeDeserializer(
        final AsPropertyTypeDeserializer src, final BeanProperty property) {
    super(src, property);
}

@Override
public TypeDeserializer forProperty(
        final BeanProperty prop) {
    return (prop == _property) ? this : new CustomTypeDeserializer(this, prop);
}

@Override
public Object deserializeTypedFromObject(
        final JsonParser jp, final DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
    JsonNode node = jp.readValueAsTree();
    Class<?> subType = findSubType(node);
    JavaType type = SimpleType.construct(subType);

    JsonParser jsonParser = new TreeTraversingParser(node, jp.getCodec());
    if (jsonParser.getCurrentToken() == null) {
        jsonParser.nextToken();
    }
    /* 16-Dec-2010, tatu: Since nominal type we get here has no (generic) type parameters,
    *   we actually now need to explicitly narrow from base type (which may have parameterization)
    *   using raw type.
    *
    *   One complication, though; can not change 'type class' (simple type to container); otherwise
    *   we may try to narrow a SimpleType (Object.class) into MapType (Map.class), losing actual
    *   type in process (getting SimpleType of Map.class which will not work as expected)
    */
    if (_baseType != null && _baseType.getClass() == type.getClass()) {
        type = _baseType.narrowBy(type.getRawClass());
    }
    JsonDeserializer<Object> deser = ctxt.findContextualValueDeserializer(type, _property);
    return deser.deserialize(jsonParser, ctxt);
}

protected Class<?> findSubType(JsonNode node) {
    Class<? extends ParentClass> subType = null;
    String cat = node.get("header").get("category").asText();
    if (cat.equals("CATEGORY1")) {
        subType = Category1Class.class;
    } else if (cat.equals("CATEGORY2")) {
        subType = Category2Class.class;
    }
    return subType;
}
}
```

In extended class we bypassed sub type identification using idResolver instead we are identifying dynamically with `category` field of `header` field.
We need `TypeResolverBuilder` to create new `CustomTypeDeserializer` instance.

```
package com.dilipkumarg.tutorials.dynamicsubtype;

import java.util.Collection;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.NamedType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.TypeDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.StdTypeResolverBuilder;


public class CustomTypeResolver extends StdTypeResolverBuilder {
    @Override
    public TypeDeserializer buildTypeDeserializer(final DeserializationConfig config, final JavaType baseType, final Collection<NamedType> subtypes) {
        return new CustomTypeDeserializer(baseType, null,
            _typeProperty, _typeIdVisible, _defaultImpl);
    }
}
```

Now we have a `CustomTypeResolver` for sub type identification, but how Jackon will know to look this class when it found 'ParentClass'?
We can do it by two ways:

1. Extending `JackonAnnotationInterceptor` with custom configuration and configure it while creating `ObjectMapper`.
2. Using `@JsonTypeResolver` annotation. This is the recommended approach as we don’t need to configure any thing.

After including type resolver our new `ParentClass` class will be:

```
package com.dilipkumarg.tutorials.dynamicsubtype;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonTypeResolver;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)
@JsonTypeResolver(CustomTypeResolver.class)
public class ParentClass {
    private Header header;
    private String nextField;
    ...
}
```

see [here](https://www.dilipkumarg.com/dynamic-polymorphic-type-handling-jackson/)