# Jackson @JsonTypeInfo property attribute assumes string value

Tags: java, jackson

Say I have some JSON like so

```
[
    {
        'type' : {
            'value': 'B'
         }
    },
    {
        'type' : {
            'value': 'C'
         }
    }
]
```

Is it possible to use jackson to use the types value property to tell jackson what polymorphic type the object is? For example, i've tried something along the lines of this without any luck

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.Property, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "B", value = B.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "C", value = C.class)
              }
)
abstract class A {
    private Type type;
}

@JsonTypeName(value = "B")
class B extends A {
}

@JsonTypeName(value = "C")
class C extends A {
}

class Type {
    private String value;
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to modify either the JSON structure, the class structure or both ?

Comment: JSON has to stay the same, class structure however can be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `String` nested in another object in JSON to discern the type doesn't seem to be supported by Jackson. You can always use a custom Deserializer for that sort of thing. It will look like this:

```
class ADeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<A> {
    @Override public A deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) p.getCodec();
        ObjectNode node = mapper.readTree(p);
        String value = node.get("type").get("value").asText();
        switch (value) {
            case "B": return mapper.treeToValue(node, B.class);
            case "C": return mapper.treeToValue(node, C.class);
            default: return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and to use it annotate the abstract class to specify the Deserializer:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = ADeserializer.class)
abstract class A {
```

and derived classes with empty `@JsonDeserialize` to avoid calling the same custom Deserializer again (`StackOverflowError`).

```
@JsonDeserialize
class B extends A {
```

No need for `@JsonTypeName`, `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` for the above.

I had a look at a few other options like a custom [JsonTypeIdResolver](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonTypeIdResolver.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38239972/1413133) that extends [AsPropertyTypeDeserializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/impl/AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.html) but couldn't get either of these to work in your case.

Comment: I thought it might come down to something like that! Thank you!