# Deserialize Json with subtypes

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization

I faced with problem during deserialization incoming Json with subtypes from external service.

I need to deserialize incoming Json into next hierarchy of classes:

```
class A {
   private String type; // by this field i can figure out concrete implementation of class C.
   private B classB;
}

class B {
   private C abstractClass;
   // other fields
}

class C {
// fields
}

class CImpl1 extends C {
}
class CImpl2 extends C {
}
```

If field "type" is in the class B i know how to place Jackson annotations, 
but in case when "field" is outside of class B i couldn't do it.

Could anyone help me with Jackson annotations in order to deserialize Json?

Comment: For the beginning you can check http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-annotations.html

Comment: Thanks @Woworks I'll check

Comment: Can you add the JSON you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: @Franjavi {
   "_links":{
      "self":"link"
   },
   "id":"id",
   "type":"thisType",
   "source":{
      "_meta":{
         "type":"sourceType"
      },
      "data":[
         {
            "_links":{
               "self":"link",
               "related":"somelinks"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

Comment: In this case "thisType" is the type for define the type of "data" of "source" field. So "source" is my class B in the example. I need to define type of "data" field of "source" type by "thisType" field. I'm trying to do this with @JsonTypeInfo

Comment: I figured out, that it's impossible to do with JsonTypeInfo annotation. I had to do it with custom deserializer for class A. And it works. It's just because i can't with JsonTypeInfo annotation define the "type" field of class A in order to deserialize subtype of class C.

Comment: Yes, seems not supported by Jackson. Here is another example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45009309/jackson-jsontypeinfo-property-attribute-assumes-string-value