# Jackson polymorphic deserialization with type property that is nested in one-level higher object

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, json-deserialization

I am stuck deserializing a JSON using Jackson.

JSON objects:

```
{
"animal": {
 "header": {
   "id": "1",
   "type": "dog"
 }
 "description": {
   "color":"black",
   "sound": "bark"
   "loyal": true
 }
}

{
"animal": {
 "header": {
   "id": "2",
   "type": "cat"
 }
 "description": {
   "color": "white",
   "sound": "meow",
   "sleepDuration": 14
 }
}

{
"plant": {
 "header": {
   "id": "5",
   "type": "rose"
 }
 "description": {
   "color": "red",
   "smell": "good"
 }
}
```

Java Classes:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type( value = Animal.class, name = "animal" ),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type( value = Plant.class, name = "plant")
})
@JsonRootName("species")
public abstract class Species {
  public Header header;
  public Description description;
//...
}
```

```java
@JsonRootName("animal")
public class Animal extends Species {
 //... 
 }
```

```java
@JsonRootName("plant")
@Getter
public class Plant extends Species {
 //...
 }
```

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        // ????????? Not sure if there is an annotation to help with this.
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "DogDescription", value = DogDescription.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "RoseDescription", value = RoseDescription.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "CatDescription", value = CatDescription.class)})
public abstract class Description {
   private String color;
}
```

```
@JsonRootName("description")
public class DogDescription {
   private Sound sound;
   private boolean loyal;
}
```

```
@JsonRootName("description")
public class CatDescription {
   private Sound sound;
   private int sleepDuration;
}
```

The serialization of `animal` succeeded. However, I have issue on how to serialize the `description` using `type` information in the header. 
`use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,` doesn't work since the type property is not under the Description Object. I have tried also to do a customTypeId resolver as described in this post : [Jackson polymorphic deserialization with type property that is nested in object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36202637/jackson-polymorphic-deserialization-with-type-property-that-is-nested-in-object). It didn't work. I think because once the species serialization is performed, Jackson would pass the JSON tree of Description. I couldn't find a way to access the type in the header.

I am wondering if there is a solution to this problem without using a custom serializer.

Comment: My gut feel on this is that JSON is intended for JavaScript associative arrays, and that there isn't necessarily a clean way to map it to the Java type system.